Text container width changes dynamically with text
The text container consists of the text coming from provider, so the text container width is dynamically changing according to the text, so I want it have a fixed width that is to cover entire width of the screen. plese help me to acheive it.
here is the code
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Recapio"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            // Display the current confidence score
            Text(
              "Confidence: $_confidence",
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
            // Display the Transcription using Provider
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                // margin: EdgeInsets.all(50),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey[200],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Text(
                    _transcription,// this is the text container that should occupy width of the whole screen
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            // Start/Stop Recording Button
            ElevatedButton.icon (
              onPressed: _toggleListening,
              icon: Icon(_isListening ? Icons.mic : Icons.mic_off),
              
              label: Text(_isListening ? "Stop Listening" : "Start Listening"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

I am new to flutter and I have tried to search for this in flutter docs and stack overflow there were few post mentioning about sizedbox.expand but after adding that in place of exapanded made the entie screen blank with error about rendering and the widgets didnt even rendered.

Wrap your Text in ConstrainedBox(constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity), child: Text ... )

This question is similar to: Flutter Text in Column auto multiline. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can add width to be double.maxFinite or double.infinity and it will take all available space.
            Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                width: double.maxFinite,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey[200],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                child: const SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Text(
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, .',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                ),
              ),



You can use MediaQuery.of(context).size.width to cover the screen's width.
Example:
Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Text('Responsive Container'),
      ),


Please don't.  That's the width of the screen, not the width of where the Text box has available to it.

Wrap your text widget in SizedBox and set width to
SizedBox(
   width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;
   child: Text(…


Please don't. That's the width of the screen, not the width of where the Text box has available to it.

yep. and this is exactly what is required, based on the content of the question
